# Running function of one application from within another application

Tags: vb.net, appdomain

I've got two standalone applications: 
First one:

```
    Namespace FirstApplication
        Class MainWindow
            Public Sub New()
                InitializeComponent()
            End Sub

            Public Function RunBatch(Parameter as String) as Double
                'Do some work
                Return SomeValue
            End Function

        End Class
    End Namespace
```

Second application:

```
    Namespace SecondApplication
        Class MainWindow
            Public Sub New()
                InitializeComponent()
            End Sub

            Public Sub RunBatch()
                'Call RunBatch() from first Application, get show the result
                Msgbox(RunBatch)
            End Function

        End Class
    End Namespace
```

Both are WPF, .Net 4.0 based. The goal is to have second application call on the first one and execute a function in it.

The key part is that both applications are used primarily independently and only occasionally second calls on the first. Because both applications need to exist as executable, I don't want to solve the problem by creating a dll of the first application - I would need to maintain both the executable and dll update to date with potentially disastrous consequences if they fall out of sync.

So the question is whether it's possible, to create an instance of first application within AppDomain of the second one and, crucially, execute functions of that instance.

Comment: Your best bet it to put the methods in a library and reference from the app you want to use it in.

Comment: The proper solution most certainly is to extract the common functionality out into a class library.  Any other option *will* be much more work and harder to maintain than doing that.

Comment: I completely agree that library would be the best, but i've had difficult previous development experience with libraries that need frequent (multiple times a day) modifications. I should read-up on debugging dlls in VS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can create one AppDomain inside of another.

Any other options you have (using WCF, or old style .NET Remoting, or crossing AppDomains) are all going to be more complicated than just making a single DLL that both applications can reference. So long as you don't change the assembly number of the shared DLL you won't have to recompile each exe if you make changes to the DLL (assuming you don't make breaking changes like changing method signatures).

Does FirstApplication have to do something to SecondApplication? Are you trying to control a feature of one application from another? If so you will need something like WCF (using Named Pipes or just a self-hosted web service). Or just trying to not have to write the same code twice? Then the simplest approach is probably to create a single DLL both applications reference.

Comment: Reflection seems to be the easiest approach, I'll have to investigate WCF as I've never worked with it. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this can be done via reflection. The process is straightforward, though not nearly as convenient as using dll.

```
Public Class CalltoExternallApp
'this is the declaration of the external application you want to run within your application
Dim newAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Mydirectory\Myfile.exe")
Public Sub Main()
            'Loads the main entry point of the application i.e. calls default constructor and assigns handle for it to MyApplication
            Dim MyApplication = newAssembly.CreateInstance("MyApplication.RootClass")
            'Get the type which will allow for calls to methods within application
            Dim MyApplicationType as Type = newAssembly.GetType("MyApplication.RootClass")
            'If calling a function, the call will return value as normal. 
            Dim Result As Object = LunaMain.InvokeMember("MyFunction", Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, MyApplication, MyParameters)
End Sub
End Class
```

Check also here for adding the event handlers to instances created via Reflection:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx